# TypeScript does not process my JSON to determine the type of the variable

Tags: node.js, typescript, types

I have static JSON, where each element has type

```
export interface DaliCommandData {
    hex?: DaliRequestSubject;
    type: DaliCommandType;
    addressRequired: boolean;
    deviceType?: DaliDeviceType;
}
```

and this is a snippet of the object, where we optionally use the `hex` and `deviceType` field. Additionally with `addressRequired`, I want to assert that an `address` parameter is passed into the class using types, rather than an error message.

```
    add_to_group: {
        type: 'command',
        addressRequired: true,
    },
    enable_device_type: {
        hex: 0xc1,
        type: 'command',
        addressRequired: false
    },
    query_battery_charge: {
        hex: 0xf1,
        type: 'query',
        addressRequired: true,
        deviceType: 1
    }
```

Since this class takes in a `commandString` (eg. query_battery_charge) to get the associated command data, I'm sure there must be a way to get typescript to understand that certain parameters exist based on the `commandString`?

Comment: you're probably looking for discriminated unions